# apache python print internal error

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x

Im newbie in apache and python
Im buy VPS and want doing site, but if my code contains error
in browser output

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@mywebsite.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

How i can print in browser real error in my code?

Comment: Why do you need the error to display in the browser? just check the server logs. Look up where they are stored, they should have more information about the error.

Comment: In Google App Engine error output in browser window,instead html